# Internal Salesforce.com Error in while inserting records of Master - Detail Object

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, master-detail

I have a scenario where I need to insert more than 60 detail records of a single master. In the same instance I have to insert the master record get the ID and then insert 60 different details of the same.

The same works flawlessly until 38 records here is the limits that are utilized in inserting 38 records:

```
17:08:53.1 (641222913)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[91]|Database.insert(List<SObject>)
17:08:53.1 (641260235)|DML_BEGIN|[91]|Op:Insert|Type:Payment_Schedules__c|Rows:38
17:08:53.1 (641283908)|LIMIT_USAGE|[91]|DML|2|150
17:08:53.1 (641291826)|LIMIT_USAGE|[91]|DML_ROWS|39|10000
17:08:53.1 (641308456)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:156
17:08:53.1 (739617623)|DML_END|[91]
17:08:53.1 (739747119)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:156
17:08:53.1 (739787515)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[91]|Database.insert(List<SObject>)
17:08:53.1 (739800747)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[92]
17:08:53.1 (739814918)|LIMIT_USAGE|[92]|SCRIPT_STATEMENTS|6645|200000
17:08:53.1 (739881176)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[92]|Bytes:8
17:08:53.1 (739900982)|DML_BEGIN|[92]|Op:Update|Type:Lending_Contract__c|Rows:1
17:08:53.1 (739919823)|LIMIT_USAGE|[92]|DML|3|150
17:08:53.1 (739930181)|LIMIT_USAGE|[92]|DML_ROWS|40|10000
17:08:53.1 (739947279)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:08:53.1 (754589970)|DML_END|[92]
17:08:53.1 (754609159)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[93]
17:08:53.1 (754620238)|LIMIT_USAGE|[93]|SCRIPT_STATEMENTS|6646|200000
17:08:53.1 (754936104)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[93]|Calculations.LendingContractID|"a004x000001d9BhAAI"
17:08:53.1 (754968258)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|01p4x000003WgvL|Calculations.CreateSchedules(Double, Double, Integer, String, Date, Date)
17:08:53.1 (754980981)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
17:08:53.764 (764240185)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
17:08:53.764 (764240185)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 3 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 40 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 189 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

17:08:53.764 (764240185)|TOTAL_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS_QUEUED|0
```

The same code fails when there are more than 38 records here is the limits usage when tried for 39 records:

```
17:08:58.1 (588262540)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[91]|Database.insert(List<SObject>)
17:08:58.1 (588307190)|DML_BEGIN|[91]|Op:Insert|Type:Payment_Schedules__c|Rows:39
17:08:58.1 (588331920)|LIMIT_USAGE|[91]|DML|2|150
17:08:58.1 (588340141)|LIMIT_USAGE|[91]|DML_ROWS|40|10000
17:08:58.1 (588356694)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:160
17:08:58.1 (610899136)|DML_END|[91]
17:08:58.1 (615098680)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
17:08:58.1 (615455839)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
17:08:58.615 (615492715)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
17:08:58.615 (615492715)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 2 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 40 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 175 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

17:08:58.615 (615492715)|TOTAL_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS_QUEUED|0
```

Do we have any kind of fix how we can solve the same...
The code is quite simple with the following insert and update patterns

- Insert MasterRecord
- for loop to create details:
- Update detailRecordList
- Update MasterRecord

Comment: an `internal salesforce error` is not necessarily a limits exception so the issue is most likely elsewhere. The problem could lie elsewhere such as a failure in a flow or process builder associated with the DML. If it were a Limits exception, the debug log would say so.

Comment: But the org is totally new, and there is no flow / process builder linked to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the limits of Salesforce fields which were getting hit multiple times. We had 3 fields over here with Currency format with length 16, and decimal 2. As these limiting values are only on the view and not on the backend we can even insert 77.8799 in these fields which will be visible as 77.88

Salesforce does gives out an error when this issue is stimulated on a single field. But when tried with the same value being inserted in three different fields of same specifications, Salesforce gave out **"Internal Salesforce.com error"**

Basically Salesforce.com errors are the largest wrapper of any type of error, and it will be given out when Salesforce is not able to throw in multiple errors of any type. As the same error popped up in my case for three different fields we had an Salesforce.com error.